# how can i Integrate React Web Component with Angular and Passing Props

Tags: reactjs, angular, web-component

I have developed a web component using React and now I want to integrate this component into my Angular application. The React web component requires certain props to function properly. How can I achieve this integration and pass props to the React component within my Angular application?

Here's what I've done so far

Imported the React web component into my Angular project.
Attempted to pass props to the React component in my Angular template.
However, I'm encountering difficulties in properly passing the props to the React component and making it work seamlessly within my Angular application.

Could someone please provide guidance or a code example demonstrating how to correctly integrate a React web component into an Angular application and pass props to it?

Comment: Are you expecting both React and  Angular to run at the same time? Or are you trying to rewrite a React component so that it works in Angular? Please include your code in the question.